# Javascript works intermittently on IE 10 in Windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer

On my client's site: http://www.jessicaandrewsevents.com/

In IE 10 on Windows 8, the javascript fails to run when going to a page directly, but works if you click a menu item to go to a page it works fine.  The link to the homepage works about 50% of the time.

I have looked at the developer tools console and no JS error is being reported.

Any help or work around would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating to a newer jQuery--1.8.0 has a known bug with IE 9 and 10 (mentioned in the release notes for 1.8.1 here: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/ and the issue http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282 "Document.ready is fired too early on IE 9/10).

Comment: Upgrading to 1.8.3 solved the problem.  Thank you